# How to remove item correctly from an array in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got 2 component in my project.

Cart List and Cart Item in my project

In the cart list I got something like this.

```
const examCartItemList = [
    {
        name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 01',
        description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
    },
    {
        name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 02',
        description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
    },
    {
        name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 03',
        description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
    },
];


const CartList = ({navigation}) => {
    const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(examCartItemList);

    const removeItem = name => {
        const filteredArray = itemList.filter(item => item.name !== name);
        setItemList(filteredArray);
    };

return (

<View style={[styles.pageContainer]}>
                    {itemList.map((cartItem, index) => (
                        <CartItem
                            removeItem={removeItem}
                            index={index}
                            key={index.toString()}
                            cartItem={cartItem}
                        />
                    ))}
                </View>
)
```

I am passing the removeItem func into the child component. Since I add the remove button in the cartItem component.

From my understanding the function will remove the item that I selected. Which is working fine.

**The thing is the `number of cart item` coming from `child component` is behaving strangely**

In my child component

I got something like this

```
const CartItem = ({cartItem, removeItem, index}) => {
  const [productCount, setProductCount] = useState(1);

  const decreaseProductCount = () => {
    if (productCount > 1) {
      setProductCount(productCount - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.componentContainer}>
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.componentImage} source={cartItem.source} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.componentContent}>
        <View style={styles.cartItemNameContainer}>
          <Text style={[styles.nameText, styles.textDescription]}>
            {cartItem.name}
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeItem(cartItem.name)}>
            <Text style={globalStyle.normalText}>X</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View> 
   </View> 
</View>
```

What happening is that as you can see in the pic. if the remove the item with name `01`. The item `01` its self is removed but the child number of count is removed differently from the parent. if I remove item `01` the count 3 should be removed but the count 7 is remove instead

Here is the pic

[image: Original]

[image: After removing]

Comment: Don't use index as key https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is because you are assigning the id value as the current index of the map operation. When you remove item 0, in the next render item 0 still exists. I think you must assign a static id to each cart item, just like this:

```
const examCartItemList = [
     {
         id: 1,
         name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 01',
         description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
     },
     {
         id: 2,
         name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 02',
         description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
     },
     {
         id: 3,
         name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 03',
         description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
     },
];
```

Also, it's a good practice to remove item by id, so maybe you can reconsider to change the removeItem logic to remove item by id.

Answer (score 0):

I have got few suggestions,

##### Use `id` in the `examCartItemList`

```
const examCartItemList = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 01',
    description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 02',
    description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Mocasines Pastoret 03',
    description: 'Leather Loafer with Penny Bar',
},
```

];

##### Use the `id` as key and pass `productCount` from here,

```
 <CartItem
     removeItem={removeItem}
     index={index} // Remove this prop if not used
     key={`${cartItem.id}`}
     cartItem={cartItem}
     productCount={itemList.length} // pass productCount from here
 />
```

##### It is always good to use a unique id to remove an item. Update `removeItem` func as follows and make sure to pass id to this function,

```
const removeItem = id => {
    const filteredArray = itemList.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    setItemList(filteredArray);
};
```

##### Remove `productCount` logic from `CartItem` component.

This should probably fix your issue.